# MS Access client: store documents in Oracle table

Tags: ms-access, oracle10g, ole

I would like to try storing documents in an attached Oracle table from MS Access, exactly like one can do with OLE Object fields in Access tables.
Is that working ? Which field type is to be used in Oracle ? Blob ? Is BFILE working as well ?
Thanks !

Comment: You might be better off asking on DBA Admin ( http://dba.stackexchange.com/ ), but I am not sure.

Comment: @Remou: good idea. Should I delete this one or may I cross post ? (And aren't the DBAs going to laugh at my Access question ?)

Comment: I think you will get away with cross posting; i. the DBAs are quite polite**, ii. there are other Access questions there, iii. this is more Oracle than Access (** at worst, snicker quietly behind their hands).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you might be able find out for yourself would be to create such a table in Access and then export it to Oracle via your ODBC connection. If the procedure was successful then you could look at the Oracle table that was created and see what column type was used to store the embedded documents.

Comment: Good idea, but I am not sure I have the authorisations for that. Any way I could ask the DBA to do it. I never tried to export via ODBC, but I will give it a try.